# Browserify+Backbone.js "ApplicationState" shared module

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, browserify, commonjs

I don't understand how to share some sort of "singleton" application-state holding object model, between different views, using browserify. 
Books and tutorials often use a global namespace such as:

```
var app = app || {};
```

I have a simple example app which consists of:

**app.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;

var MenuView = require('./views/MenuView');
var ContainerView = require('./views/ContainerView');

new MenuView();
new ContainerView();
```

**MenuView.js**

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var ApplicationState = require('../models/ApplicationState');

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#menuView', 
    events: {
        'click .menuLink': 'changePage'
    },
    changePage: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var viewName = $(event.target).attr('data-view');
        ApplicationState.set('currentView',viewName);
    }
});
```

**ContainerView.js**

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var ApplicationState = require('../models/ApplicationState');

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#containerView', 
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo( ApplicationState, 'change', this.render );   
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( ApplicationState.get('currentView') );
    },
    close: function() {
        this.stopListening();
    }
});
```

This seems working using this approach:

**ApplicationState.js**
    var Backbone = require('backbone');

```
var ApplicationState = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        currentView: 'TransactionListView'
    }
});

module.exports = new ApplicationState();
```

Is the ApplicationState module really created only once (caching) ?
Or is there the risk of recreating / resetting the module?

What is the best practice for my use case? Thank you a lot.

Comment: I guess it is ok, you may check how many instances of ApplicationState will be created by adding console.count('Application State') within ApplicationState.js file and see output in console.

Comment: `this.$el.html( ApplicationState.get('currentView') );` should probably be `this.$el.html( ApplicationState.get('currentView').$el );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there will only be one ApplicationState in the example you gave.  Browserify executes anything following `module.exports =` as soon as the js file is run and then anything that requires that file is passed a reference to the result.

However it’s generally better practice to avoid sharing state this way between views and instead use a parent view that delegates to subviews. There are a number of ways to set this up.  For ideas on best practices for organizing a backbone app, check out this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lm05e5sJaE8

For the example you gave I would highly consider using [Backbone's Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router).
In your example you have a nav that changes the "main" view.  Backbone.Router intercepts navigation and checks it against your specified routes calling your view method.  For instance:

**router.js**

```
module.exports = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        this.ContainerView = new ContainerView();
    },
    routes: {
        'transactions': 'showTransactionListView',
        'transaction/:id': 'showTransactionDetailView'
    },
    showTransactionListView: function() {
        this.ContainerView.render('TransactionListView');
    },
    showTransactionDetailView: function(id) {
        this.ContainerView.render('TransactionDetailView', id);
    }
});
```

Then any link to `#transations` (or just `transactions` if you're using [Backbone History](http://backbonejs.org/#History)) will call your `ContainerView.render('TransactionListView')`.  And, as a bonus, if you reload the page you'll still be looking at `TransactionListView`.

Other notes:

- You'll want to make sure you discard old views when you replace them (by calling `.remove()` on them) so as to avoid memory leaks.  [Further Reading](http://blog.42floors.com/structure-render-views-backbone/)
- You can add some flexibility to your router and use a controller pattern to render subviews with [this nifty plugin](https://github.com/brentertz/backbone-route-control)

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I'll take a look to the talk. Can you explain me how routers would fit in my example please? Thank you again!

Comment: Sure.  I've updated my answer with a (minimal) router example.